# How can I send the message to all users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here, I'm defining a recipient by the params.
What if I want to send the message to all the users who has confirmed already at once?
How can I write?

Anyone has any idea?

**controller**

```
    recipient = User.find_by_username(params[:messages][:recipient]) 

    if recipient.confirmed_at.nil?
        redirect_to messages_sent_path 
        flash[:notice] = "This user hasn't confirmed yet!"   
        return
    end

    params[:messages][:subject] = 'no subject' if params[:messages][:subject].blank?
    subject = params[:messages][:subject] 
    body = params[:messages][:body]

    if current_user != recipient 
        current_user.send_message(recipient, body, subject) 
        redirect_to :controller => 'messages', :action => 'sent' 
        flash[:notice] = "Sent!" 
    else 
        redirect_to :controller => 'messages', :action => 'received' 
        flash[:notice] = "Cannot send to yourself!" 
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using mysql / sqlite3

```
users = User.where('confirmed_at IS NOT NULL')
users.each do |user|
  current_user.send_message(user, body, subject) 
end
```

Comment: Thanks:) Please let me try that:)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `users.each do |recipient|` ??